# Finding unghosted pages

Tags: powershell, unghosting

Is there a way to find how many unghosted pages there are in a site collection ? May be with queries in content database or powershell cmdlets ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`Get-SPCustomizedPages` PowerShell cmdlets](http://www.falchionconsulting.com/PowerShellViewer/Default.aspx?Version=SP2013&Cmdlet=Get-SPCustomizedPages) written by Gary LaPointe.